# Display the multiple values from a drop down

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

here i have a sheet, in that we can find the sum of diff categories using query function by selecting from drop down list. but here I can select one month only at a time can i find the amount of January and February at the same time by adding another column for another month or in any other way. here I can find the sales of one month at a time. I want to find sales of two or three months at time.

Please help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdtrtdNQBsxiZt8FjvbaE9omCBs8x8vRgp0r2bc1_7c/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you can make a drop down list with multiple choice in Google Sheets.
But there are some alternatives.

1. List of tick boxes (here as list of months)
2. Manual input of multiple values separated by comma or something else.

I give both:

[image]

Months are selected as list separated by | so it can be used as regex inside 'matches' clause in query
This generates list of months:

```
=join("|",query({A2:B7;C2:D7},"select Col2 where Col1 = true "))
```

Window with manual input works similar way

```
=substitute(substitute(F3,", ",","),",","|")
```

It takes its contents, removes spaces that are adjacent to comma, adds separator | instead of comma. It's case sensitive and I don't know how to get rid of this (?i) does not work within query.

All together it looks like on the picture and combined formula is:

=query(ORDERS!A1:R14,"select A, B, C , D where
A matches '"&join("|",query({A2:B7;C2:D7},"select Col2 where Col1 = true "))&"' and
B matches '"&substitute(substitute(F3,", ",","),",","|")&"'",0)

Here is my solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQ5_VdxZ-t4MqPbLqzb8q-saqp5Jqz3hVXeWHX_Lls4/copy

Comment: thanks but why Hair care & Lip care not working ? pls fix that too my friend

Comment: please fin your sheet and check with Hair care

Comment: Hi. I kindly remind that this is not a software house where you order services and expect people to do the whole job for you. I've mentioned in my answer that my solution will not work for with 2 word names. Please find edits to my answer - now it should work with 2 words too. But still it's not a product - it's still case sensitive and may have more issues.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your spreadsheet to do my testing. Here's what you can do.

1. Add another row of the same exact selection found on your "A" row.
2. Change your formula to this: `={query(ORDERS!A1:R,"Select * where A contains '"&$A2&"' and B contains '"&$B2&"'",1);query(ORDERS!A1:R,"Select * where A contains '"&$A3&"' and B contains '"&$B3&"'",0)}`

What this does it run an array of two sets of formulas (In this case 2 queries) for the same set of data.

Here's the screenshot of the output if you're interested.

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Eijx.png)

Comment: I tried your formula to my sheet and it works ok when we fill all the drop down but when we fill only dropdown in A2. the values comes under are repeated. pls go to my sheet there u can see the output for your formula

Comment: id we select Feb in two dropdowns the output comes repeat. please check this and solve this please. formula is there in the sheet